# Ignore OnMouseDown when scene is reloaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene with a transparent button filling the entire screen. The button is used as a multipurpose button that makes the player jump if the game is in play. But if the game is over and the button is clicked the scene will be reloaded.

This button has an event trigger: On pointer down attached, which calls the "Action" function shown below.

```
void Action() {
    if (game_isOver) {
        SceneManager.Loadscene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    } else {
        Jump();
    }
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the scene is loaded, the button detects a press and calls `Action()` again. And it is too fast to avoid by pressing the button quickly.

What is the best way to avoid this. I don't particularly want to have a delay to give the user time to finish their click because i want them to be able to double click in order to quickly get into game play.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use coroutine function **LoadSceneAsync** to load the scene that you can handle the situation of loading.

```
bool isLoading;

void Action() {
    if (game_isOver) {
        if(!isLoading){
            StartCoroutine(LoadNewScene());
        }
    } else {
        Jump();
    }
}

IEnumerator LoadNewScene() {

    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
    {
        isLoading = true;
        Debug.Log("Loading progress: " + asyncOperation.progress);
        yield return null;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hi this code doesn't work. Are you meant to be starting the coroutine anywhere?